# changing the active object with python

Tags: python, scripting

I have 2 objects in my scene. I only want to do the following simple thing and for some reason every solution I encounter online fails.
I want to iterate over all the objects in the scene. for each, I want to set it active and scale it up by 2. Tried something like the following:

```py
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    # Here I need some line that makes obj the active object!
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(...)
```

another thing that I fail to do is add a cube and then a sphere and then go back the cube and add a boolean modifier that specifies the sphere (as I cannot change the active object, it tries to assign a boolean modifier with itself and fails).
thanks.

I use blender 3.4 if it matters.

Comment: There's plenty of information in the Blender docs about using python. [Here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) for instance.

Answer (score 2):

For operating on the objects using ".ops.", we can either add objects to the selection set using method object's select_set method.

Another way without disturbing the current context and selection is to override the context temporarily using temp_override

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    # Here I need some line that makes obj the active object!
    #bpy.ops.transform.resize(...)

     with bpy.context.temp_override(selected_objects=[obj]):
        print('Operating on obj',obj)
        bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(2, 2, 2))
```

For the second part of the question,

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
cube=bpy.data.objects[-1]

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=1, location=(0.5, 0, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
sphere=bpy.data.objects[-1]

with bpy.context.temp_override(selected_objects=[cube], object=cube, active_object=cube):
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].object = sphere
```

Comment: @GalSuchetzky, did this help?